# Software to solve systems of boolean equations

Tags: boolean, equation-solving

I'm looking for software to solve systems of boolean equations. I know this can be an NP hard problem, but from what I understand equations might be solved in polynomial time.
What I had in mind was something which implemented the algorithms outlined in https://folk.uib.no/nmagf/SolvingBoolean.pdf

My current equation sets are written in terms of AND and INVERTERS (aiger), but I could convert these into any other form.

I had some look at https://github.com/triska/clpb which might do the job, but I don't know how to run the Prolog to extracts the results automatically. This is how I run it interactively:

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).
and_gate(X, Y, Z) :- sat(Z =:= (X*Y)).
inverter_gate(X, Z) :- sat(Z =:= ~(X)).

id00040(R1, INP1, INP3, Z) :-
    inverter_gate(INP1, T1),
    inverter_gate(INP3, T2),
    and_gate(T1, R1, T3),
    and_gate(T2, T3, Z).
```

Then run it:

```
?- id00040(0,INP1,INP3,0), labeling([INP1,INP3]).
INP1 = INP3, INP3 = 0 ;
INP1 = 0,
INP3 = 1 ;
INP1 = 1,
INP3 = 0 ;
INP1 = INP3, INP3 = 1.
```

Which indicate that all the inputs are don't care. Is there a way to extract this other than building a table and conclude that all the inputs are don't care? Also how can I make Prolog keep running to generate all the outputs other than hitting return?

And more importantly are there any other software packages out there to do this?